# pandas resample - 5 minute blocks (not every 5th minute of the hour)

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-resample

I have some data taken every minute and I want to resample it in 5 minute segments.

```
df.resample("5T").mean()
```

This has the effect of resampling to every fifth minute of the hour. i.e
12:00,12:05,12:10,12:15 etc.

What if my last data point was 12:07

Is there a way to resample it in 5 minute blocks to the result would be (also backwards so the last newest time 100% contains data from 5 minutes)

12:07, 12:02, 11:07  etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `origin` parameter by first value of `index`:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03 12:07:00', periods=10, freq='min')
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(10)}, index=rng)  

df = df.resample("5T", origin=df.index[0]).mean()
print (df)
                     a
2017-04-03 12:07:00  2
2017-04-03 12:12:00  7
```

Comment: If only i had read the documentation properly !!